# Geometric shape recognition using c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, shapes

lately I need to integrate geometric shape recognition into a drawing application that I am working on and I am looking for c++ libraries that could help with that.The idea is like this :For example when a user draws something that is close to a circle the program should draw a regular circle in the bounding rectangle.It would be great to do the same on rectangles,triangles etc.

Suggestions and pointers should really be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) for any sort of image processing and recognition. It supports what you describe out of the box and runs in C++.

If you don't want to use C++, [ShapeMatcher](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~dmac/ShapeMatcher/) might be what you're looking for (or along the lines of it)

Comment: ... and I understand that you're not processing images, however it could still work with what you want to do.